# Edit linewidth in tikzcd with pdfrender

Tags: tikz-pgf, rendering

I'm using the pdfrender package to get a little bit stronger text thickness in my document. However, it seems to work oddly within tikz figures: the strokes look way more dark than they do in main document. I managed to fix the arrows width, but I don't know how to fix the thickness of the symbols that I put above the arrows (see image).
[image]
Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%% to get stronger strokes
\usepackage{pdfrender,xcolor} \pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.075pt,LineCapStyle=Round}

\makeatletter
\let\normalrender\PdfRender@NormalColorHook
\let\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\@empty
\newcommand*{\textnormalrender}[1]{
\begingroup\normalrender#1\endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd} \usetikzlibrary{babel,cd,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.1pt}}

\begin{tikzcd}

K(\alpha) \ar[r,"\sim"] \ar[rrr, bend right=15,"\tau"] & K[x]/(m_\alpha(x)) \ar[r, "\tilde{\tau}"] & K_1[x]/(\tilde{m}_\alpha(x)) \ar[r, "\sim"] & K_1(\beta)

\end{tikzcd}

\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please share with us a code, by which you produce showed image. The best in form of MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document), Help us too help you!

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. See edited post

Comment: even after correcting two error your code doesn't compile. You should test code that you post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: math-display environments don't like blank lines in the editor and to have `equation*` you need to load `amsmath` package.

Then, you can change the labels' weight the same way you changed the overall font weight in a `tikzcd` environment. In addition, it will be better to make this change in the preamble, not inside the `equation` environment.

An example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pdfrender,xcolor} \pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.075pt,LineCapStyle=Round}

\makeatletter
\let\normalrender\PdfRender@NormalColorHook
\let\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\@empty
\newcommand*{\textnormalrender}[1]{
\begingroup\normalrender#1\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd} \usetikzlibrary{babel,quotes}
%It might be better to set this globally
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.1pt},%
         /tikz/commutative diagrams/labels={line width=0.08pt}}

\begin{document}

For comparison: $\tau\sim\tilde{\tau}$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
K(\alpha) \ar[r,"\sim"] \ar[rrr, bend right=15,"\tau"] & K[x]/(m_\alpha(x)) \ar[r, "\tilde{\tau}"] & K_1[x]/(\tilde{m}_\alpha(x)) \ar[r, "\sim"] & K_1(\beta)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I just made a change that is visually obvious, but you will need to adjust the weight of the labels editing the line

```
/tikz/commutative diagrams/labels={line width=0.08pt}
```

Comment: perfect! thank you